# How to listen for changes on DynamoDB with Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working on a VR application, and need to listen for changes on a DynamoDB table. I've managed to connect to the table through the AWS SDK with Unity, however right now the controller only pulls the data from the table once. How could I set it up so that it triggers a method when the value on the table changes (Similar to how firebase does it)?

Here's a sample of my code:

```
public class DBListenerController: MonoBehaviour {
    private IAmazonDynamoDB client;
    private DynamoDBContext context;
    private AWSCredentials credentials;

    void Start() {
        UnityInitializer.AttachToGameObject(this.gameObject);
        AWSConfigs.HttpClient = AWSConfigs.HttpClientOption.UnityWebRequest;

        credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials ("Identity pool ID", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        context = new DynamoDBContext(client);

        PerformReadOperation();
    }

    public void PerformReadOperation()
    {
        // Retrieve the table data 
        DataObject dataRetrieved = null;
        context.LoadAsync<DataObject>("HASH",(result)=>
            {
                if(result.Exception == null )
                {
                    dataRetrieved = result.Result as DataObject;
                    onValueChanged(dataRetrieved.value);
                }
            });

    }

    void onValueChanged(string changedValue) {
        Debug.Log("New Value: ", changedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't find such functionality in the docs .. are you sure it can be done at all? Alternative might be repeated polls and compare the data?

Comment: This can help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html You'll still need to code how the notification reaches your app.

Comment: The usual way is to connect a lambda function to the dynamodb stream and further stream the changes using some pubsub service like pusher.com or pubnub. AppSync can do this by design.